# python 2.7 for mit open courseware class 6.00SC code ps1a.py

Tags: python

Hello and thank you in advance for any help to my issue. I am 2 weeks into coding with no experience at all before this. This is my second code assignment and I have been working on it for 1 week to no avail.

*the result of my program must be this:*

> Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: 4800
>
> Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: .2   Enter
>   the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: .02
>
> Month: 1
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $96.0
>
> Principle paid: $16.0
>
> Remaining balance: $4784.0
>
> Month: 2
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $95.68
>
> Principle paid: $15.95
>
> Remaining balance: $4768.05
>
> Month: 3
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $95.36
>
> Principle paid: $15.89
>
> Remaining balance: $4752.16
>
> Month: 4
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $95.04
>
> Principle paid: $15.84
>
> Remaining balance: $4736.32
>
> Month: 5
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $94.73
>
> Principle paid: $15.79
>
> Remaining balance: $4720.53
>
> Month: 6
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $94.41
>
> Principle paid: $15.73
>
> Remaining balance: $4704.8
>
> Month: 7
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $94.1
>
> Principle paid: $15.69
>
> Remaining balance: $4689.11
>
> Month: 8
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $93.78
>
> Principle paid: $15.63
>
> Remaining balance: $4673.48
>
> Month: 9
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $93.47
>
> Principle paid: $15.58
>
> Remaining balance: $4657.9 Month: 10 Minimum monthly payment: $93.16
>
> Principle paid: $15.53
>
> Remaining balance: $4642.37
>
> Month: 11
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $92.85
>
> Principle paid: $15.48
>
> Remaining balance: $4626.89
>
> Month: 12
>
> Minimum monthly payment: $92.54
>
> Principle paid: $15.43
>
> Remaining balance: $4611.46
>
> RESUL T
>
> Total amount paid: $1131.12
>
> Remaining balance: $4611.46*

*My hints are:*

> - Use the round function.
>
> To help you get started, here is a rough outline of the stages you
>   should probably follow inwriting your code:
>
> 1. Retrieve user input.
> 2. Initialize some state variables. Remember to find the monthly
>      interest rate from the annual interest rate taken in as input.
> 3. For each month:
>
>    - Compute the new balance. This requires computing the
>        minimum monthly payment and figuring out how much will be paid to
>        interest and how much will be paid to the principal.
>    - Update the outstanding balance according to how much principal was paid off.
>    - Output the minimum monthly payment and the remaining balance. Keep
>        track of the total amount of paid over all the past months so far.
> 4. Print out the result statement with the total amount paid and the
>      remaining balance. Use these ideas to guide the creation of your
>      code.

*state variables are*;

> Minimum monthly payment = Minimum monthly payment rate x Balance
>   (Minimum monthly payment gets split into interest paid and principal
>   paid)
>
> Interest Paid = Annual interest rate / 12 months x Balance
>
> Principal paid = Minimum monthly payment – Interest paid
>
> Remaining balance = Balance – Principal paid
>
> I am working in Idle and testing with "run". My thought is to;
>
> -get "raw_input" first, test.
>
> -state variables- test
>
> -make a for loop/print statement-test
>
> -get the year end balances to print-test

My code so far is this:

```
x = float(raw_input ('Enter credit card balance:'))
y = float(raw_input ('Enter annual interest rate:'))
z = float(raw_input ('Enter minimum monthly payment rate:')
mmp = x*z               #minimal monthly payment
ip = float(y /(12*x))  # Interest paid (annual interest rate/12 months       x Balance
pp = mmp- ip               #Principal paid
rb = x - pp              #remaining balance
    for i in range (1,12+1
        print ('Month: %s' %(i))
        print ('Minimum Monthly Payment:%.2f' %(mmp))
        print ('Principal Paid: % .2f' % (pp))
        print ('Remaining Balance: %.2f' %(rb))
```

> I get an error message after run that says "there is an error in your
>   program: invalid syntax" and the "mmp" on line 4 is highlighted in
>   red.

I have tried a colin after the last `raw_input` line, indentations, trying a "def" function at line 4, and a lot of other combinations and I can't get past this.

The same code was running a little better before I had the "float" before the `raw_input`, but I couldn't figure out the "round" function to make the answer only 2 decimal places.

If anyone is in NYC and would sit with me I would be grateful and reciprocal.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: You are missing a closing parentheses `)` on your third line...

Comment: Also on the for loop

Comment: I upvoted you but not sure how well SO responds to these kind of questions in general, maybe a forum is a better place for learning? Also https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/ I think might be good. Anyways best of luck

Comment: Actually one more thing is to please use an IDE (integrated development environment), it will automatically inform you of such issues. I recommend Pycharm (despite how bloated and slow it is, I find it has a lot of useful features)

Comment: @information_interchange I personally find using an IDE *bad* from a pedagogic POV (hell, I don't use one professionally), especially in a nice, clean, easy to write language like Python.

Comment: Self study or are you taking it via edX?

Comment: @wwii MIT Opencourseware

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga ..... thanks so much .

Comment: wwii - self study no credit free course

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga --- It Worked!! I can't believe I missed the last ) ...and took away the indentation from the For loop.                                                               Thanks again

Comment: I like the way you tried asking the question